# SwiftUI squeezes parent view when modal shows keyboard

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14

While working with SwiftUI I noticed a very unusual behavior. On iOS 14 when showing the keyboard on a modal screen the parent view also gets squeezed. To show what I mean I made a short demonstrator view and a short gif which shows the issue. You can find that [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDcfO.gif).

```
struct SqueezTestView: View {
    @State var isModalPresented = false
    @State var text = ""
    @State var colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue, .orange, .pink, .purple, .yellow]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<colors.count) { index in
                    colors[index]
                        .animation(.linear(duration: 1))
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Squeez")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Shuffel") { colors.shuffle() }, trailing: Button("Modal") { isModalPresented = true })
            .sheet(isPresented: $isModalPresented) {
                NavigationView {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Test", text: $text, onCommit: {isModalPresented = false})
                            .padding()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Modal", displayMode: .inline)
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Done") { isModalPresented = false })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that only the modal view gets squeezed and parent view stays the same. In this case the parent view gets animated every time I dismiss the modal while the keyboard is visible. Is there anything I missed or are there any known fixes to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958912/ios-14-swiftui-keyboard-lifts-view-automatically). The key was to set

```
.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
```

on the parent view.