# How to stop SwiftUI from moving TextField up when the keyboard is opened?

Tags: ios, swiftui, textfield

I have a TextField near the top of the screen, followed by a spacer and more content below. The TextField moves outside of the screen when the keyboard is opened.

I've tried adding `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)`, separating the TextField from the rest of the content into two VStacks nestled in a ZStack, and a few other things found online, but nothing seems to do the trick so far.

Example:

[image]

Code to reproduce:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Text", text: $text)
                .font(.largeTitle.weight(.medium))
                .padding()
            
            Spacer()
            
            VStack {
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
            }
            .padding()
            
            VStack {
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
                Text("Content")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
    }
}
```

Comment: this SO post may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63968241/swiftui-in-ios14-keyboard-avoidance-issues-and-ignoressafearea-modifier-issues

Comment: Very informative! I noticed the TextField doesn't move if I put the `Spacer()` / `Color.clear` above the TextField, but not if I put it below. What I need is to have the TextField near the top of the screen, empty space, and the rest of the content at the bottom — and nobody move when the keyboard opens. I also tried the `GeometryReader` hack, which does make the TextField move less, but it's not static.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I was able to find a way to make your textfield stay on the screen (without moving) and your texts not to move at all. I had to use a GeometryReader, that for some reason keeps the TextField in place, and a ScrollView with a custom modifier that dismisses the keyboard on drag:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Text", text: $text)
                        .font(.largeTitle.weight(.medium))
                        .padding(.top)

                    VStack {
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                    }
                    .padding()

                    VStack {
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                        Text("Content")
                    }
                    .padding()

                    Spacer(minLength: geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom) // Add spacer to account for safe area bottom

                }
                .padding()
                .keyboardDismissOnDrag() // Dismiss keyboard on drag
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func keyboardDismissOnDrag() -> some View {
        modifier(KeyboardDismissOnDragGesture())
    }
}

struct KeyboardDismissOnDragGesture: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.gesture(DragGesture().onChanged { _ in
            UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

Let me know how that worked out for you!

Comment: That's great! The only thing is that I need the Spacer to be between the TextField and the content (so the content is bottom-aligned), which doesn't play well with the ScrollView—which doesn't take up all the available V space. So I removed the ScrollView and now the content below may or may not move, depending on its height. It just happens that it doesn't move in my real app — which in essence fixes the problem. Thank you!