# SwiftUI Form with Sections Texteditor moving up when Keyboard appears

Tags: swiftui, textfield

i have a problem and read so many Solutions here on Stack but nothing really worked. I have an Form View with different sections, TextFields and at the end one Texteditor. When i click the Texteditor the Editor in the Form should go up over the Keyboard.

My Code:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
            Form{
                Section{TextField}
                Section{TextField}
             
                Section{
                    ZStack{
                        TextEditor
                    }
                }
                Section{
                    ZStack{
                    TextEditor(text: $info)
                        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                    Text(info).opacity(0).padding(.all, 8)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(alignment: .top)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                self.addUser = false
                
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
            }))
        }.onTapGesture {
            UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        }
       }.navigationBarTitle("Kunden Hinzufügen", displayMode: .inline)
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 14 SwiftUI Keyboard lifts view automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958912/ios-14-swiftui-keyboard-lifts-view-automatically)

Comment: Hey, no this doesn't work for me the TextEditor and the whole View is still not moving up.

Comment: Hi @HogirAkan, did you manage to solve this problem?