# SwiftUI iOS14 - Disable keyboard avoidance

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, ios14

Is there a way to disable the native keyboard avoidance on iOS14?

There is no keyboard avoidance in iOS13, so I want to implement my own, but when I do the native one on iOS14 is still active, so both my implementation and the native one run at the same time, which I don't want.

My deployment target is iOS13, so I need a solution for both iOS13 *and* iOS14.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 14 SwiftUI Keyboard lifts view automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958912/ios-14-swiftui-keyboard-lifts-view-automatically)

Comment: No, I need it to work on iOS 13 also

Comment: There is no *keyboard avoidance* on iOS 13. And the above solution won't do anything on iOS 13, so it should work with your code.

Comment: As I sad, I have written my own keyboard avoidance logic (which works on iOS 13), but I need to turn of the iOS 14 native keyboard avoidance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `if #available(iOS 14.0, *)` if you want to adapt the iOS 14 code so it compiles on iOS 13.

Here is an adapted version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64016326/8697793) to work on both iOS 13 and iOS 14:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            VStack {
                content
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
        } else {
            VStack {
                content
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    var content: some View {
        Spacer()
        TextField("asd", text: self.$text)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, using  iOS 13.2, I had to use `.all` instead of `.bottom`. Either way, thanks for posting an answer to this.

Comment: Maybe for simple views like this (filled with just spacers) this works. But there may be a case when you have a complex view, with custom header and many texts/buttons/textfields. In that case the view might still get pushed up, despite using `.ignoreSafeArea` modifier, so the solution to that would be to embed your view in `GeometryReader` and add the modifier to it instead of the former

Answer (score 5):

If you're still having issues with content being pushed around by the keyboard, Levan's comment solved this for me.

Re-posting as an answer so it's easier to find.

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { _ in
        VStack {
            //content
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            ModalWithTextFieldThatPushesUpParentContent()
        }
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) //keyboard avoidance
}
```

This is especially annoying when a Sheet view has a textfield and the keyboard pushes the parent content up.

1. Need to add the ignore code to the parent view
2. Add a GeometryReader, even if you're not using it
3. If you are using a NavigationStack the GeometryReader needs to be inside the NavigationStack