# SwiftUI ScrollView image as background error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

Thanks for taking your time to help others :)

### Bug description:

I can apply a color to the ScrollView background, and adjusts perfectly.

But if I try to set an image as background, the result is not correct, it expands over to the TextField and even safeArea.

I need this because I'm building a chat. And **I can't use a ZStack** to put the image under the ScrollView, it's complex to explain why.

### Simple piece of code to test it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView() {
                LazyVStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    ForEach(1..<201, id: \.self) { num in
                        Text("Message \(num)")
                    }
                }
            }
//            .background(Color.red) // Good result, adjusted where I want to
            .background(Image("chatBackground")) // Bad result, expands to TextField and safe area
            
            TextField("Your text here", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .padding()
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationTitle("Example app")
    }
}
```

### Results:

1. Good result (using a color):
   [image: Good result (using a color)]
2. Bad result (using the image):
   [image: Bad result (using the image)]

### Questions

1. How can I apply an image as background?
2. Why does it extends down to the very bottom?

### EDIT

This is the result of Timmy's answer. Almost the thing but it moves when keyboard appears.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the background of the `TextField` to white (or whatever color you need):

```
TextField("Your text here", text: $text)       
    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    .padding()
    .background(Color.white)
```

**Update:**

In order for the image to bound itself correctly, you need to use the `.clipped()` modifier after the background one:

```
.background {
    Image("chatBackground")
        .resizable() //recommended
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) //recommended
}.clipped()
```

To make the image ignore the keyboard, you need to wrap the image inside a `GeometryReader` & add `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)` (Credit to [@pawello2222](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64016326/13278922)):

```
.background {
    GeometryReader { _ in
        Image("chatBackground")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    }.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
}.clipped()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this isn't a valid solution: still extends in the background, even to the safe area. So this just sets the TextField's background, on top of scrollview's background.

Comment: Almost it, but image is supposed not to shrink when keyboard is shown.

Comment: Whoa thanks! Still got this question (any idea?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75312177/swiftui-scrollview-does-not-respond-to-keyboard but your answer solves this so damn good. Thank you!!