# How to stop the view from moving up when the keyboard shows up

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am struggling to stop the view in the image below from moving up when the keyboard appears on the screen. I have tried some approaches that I found here such as adding `GeometryReader` or `ignoresafearea` but they did not work.

Any hints would be appreciated.

[image: this image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchWord = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Set the wallpaper
            Image("image1")
                .opacity(0.9)
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(Date())")
                        Spacer()
                        if !searchWord.isEmpty {
                            Button("Clear") {
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                        TextField("Search words", text: $searchWord)
                    }
                }
                .overlay {
                    Capsule().fill(.clear)
                }
                // End of the search bar
                // Australian flag
                Image("image2")
                Text("G'day!")
                Text("Click the button below!")
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }) {
                        Text("Score") }
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }) {
                        Text("Word List")
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }) {
                        Text("Start")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When asking a question it helps if your code is a [mcve] - Something that we can paste directly into Xcode and have run.  Your code is missing pieces such as properties, functions and closing braces.

Comment: Even when adding the missing pieces it doesn't render the view you have shown in your image

Comment: First off, not even by adding the missing brackets I'm able to replicate your issue. The keyboard is not pushing up the content of the screen. Add more details and better code that we don't have to complete for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 14 SwiftUI Keyboard lifts view automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958912/ios-14-swiftui-keyboard-lifts-view-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want all views to not be pushed up by the keyboard, just add the following code

```
ZStack {
    ...
}
.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
```

But if you just want the background image not to deform when pushed up by the keyboard, make the following modifications

```
ZStack {
     Image("image1")
         .opacity(0.9)
         .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
     ...
}
```

The answer from the person in front can also help you